# How to use OAuth Authorization Code for CLIs

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, authorization, command-line-interface

Trying to allow a CLI I'm developing to "login" via web browser and obtain an access token for the user's account, similar to how gcloud and github's CLIs do it. I realize it'll be using the OAuth Authorization Code flow.

But what about the `client_secret`?
I've found out that github cli just doesn't care about exposing it, and it's right there in the source code: https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/6a8deb1f5a9f2aa0ace2eb154523f3b9f23a05ae/internal/authflow/flow.go#L25-L26

Why is this not a problem? or is it?

I'm not yet using OAuth for the cli's login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STANDARDS**

The CLI app is a native public client and should use authorization code flow + PKCE  rather than a fixed client secret. It should also follow the flow from
[RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.3) and receive the browser response using a local HTTP (loopback) URI.

**THIS IMPLEMENTATION**

Looks like the github code [here](https://github.com/cli/oauth/blob/main/webapp/webapp_flow.go) uses a client secret and does not use PKCE. You may have to provide a client secret if using this library, but it cannot be kept secret from users. Any user could easily view it, eg with an HTTP proxy tool.

**CODE**

If the infrastructure enables you to follow the standards, aim for something similar to this Node.js code.

```js
 * The OAuth flow for a console app
 */
export async function login(): Promise<string> {

    // Set up the authorization request
    const codeVerifier = generateRandomString();
    const codeChallenge = generateHash(codeVerifier);
    const state = generateRandomString();
    const authorizationUrl = buildAuthorizationUrl(state, codeChallenge);

    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {

        let server: Http.Server | null = null;
        const callback = async (request: Http.IncomingMessage, response: Http.ServerResponse) => {

            if (server != null) {
                
                // Complete the incoming HTTP request when a login response is received
                response.write('Login completed for the console client ...');
                response.end();
                server.close();
                server = null;

                try {

                    // Swap the code for tokens
                    const accessToken = await redeemCodeForAccessToken(request.url!, state, codeVerifier);
                    resolve(accessToken);

                } catch (e: any) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            }
        }

        // Start an HTTP server and listen for the authorization response on a loopback URL, according to RFC8252
        server = Http.createServer(callback);
        server.listen(loopbackPort);
        
        // Open the system browser to begin authentication
        Opener(authorizationUrl);
    });
}


/*
 * Build a code flow URL for a native console app
 */
function buildAuthorizationUrl(state: string, codeChallenge: string): string {

    let url = authorizationEndpoint;
    url += `?client_id=${encodeURIComponent(clientId)}`;
    url += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}`;
    url += '&response_type=code';
    url += `&scope=${scope}`;
    url += `&state=${encodeURIComponent(state)}`;
    url += `&code_challenge=${encodeURIComponent(codeChallenge)}`;
    url += '&code_challenge_method=S256';
    return url;
}

/*
 * Swap the code for tokens using PKCE and return the access token
 */
async function redeemCodeForAccessToken(responseUrl: string, requestState: string, codeVerifier: string): Promise<string> {

    const [code, responseState] = getLoginResult(responseUrl);
    if (responseState !== requestState) {
        throw new Error('An invalid authorization response state was received');
    }

    let body = 'grant_type=authorization_code';
    body += `&client_id=${encodeURIComponent(clientId)}`;
    body += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}`;
    body += `&code=${encodeURIComponent(code)}`;
    body += `&code_verifier=${encodeURIComponent(codeVerifier)}`;

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body,
    };

    const response = await fetch(tokenEndpoint, options);
    if (response.status >= 400) {
        const details = await response.text();
        throw new Error(`Problem encountered redeeming the code for tokens: ${response.status}, ${details}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    return data.access_token;
}
```

Comment: That was what i thought too, but the github cli's approach threw me off.
Any clue why they embed the client_secret in the cli, or why that's not "very bad"?

Comment: You can't always control other people's implementations. Many providers use non standard ones. Aim for code similar to that above for your own solution. if possible.